# Is there any possibilities to extract string from a value and convert to date value

Tags: shell

I am looking for possibilities to extract a string from a value and populate them as date in another column. Also, I have some different kinds of scenario here.

scenario 1:
Below is the csv- comma-separated one. Here, the column filename has the date in it which is in string format.So, I need to grep that specific string and convert and populate into new column with exact date format.

```
filename    filesize    data_received_dt    tname   createdt
ccaa/01APR2018-revised/ 0   2019-01-17T06:16:59.000Z    sample  2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
ccaa/01APR2018/content_01APR2018-00000.csv  115814528   2018-12-05T23:38:10.000Z    live    2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
ccaa/01APR2018-revised/content_01APR2018-00001.csv  116584541   2018-12-05T23:38:09.000Z    test    2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
ccaa/01JUN2018-revised/content_01JUN2018-00002.csv  117363985   2018-12-05T23:38:09.000Z    sample  2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
ccaa/10JUL2018/content_10JUL2018-00002.csv  117363985   2018-12-05T23:38:09.000Z    sample  2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
ccaa/21AUG2018-revised/content_21AUG2018-00002.csv  117363985   2018-12-05T23:38:09.000Z    sample  2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
```

the output should be as below. Also, the column end_dt will have same value as start_dt as per the requirement.

```
filename                                            start_dt    end_dt      filesize    data_received_dt            name    createdt
ccaa/01APR2018-revised/                             1-Apr-18    1-Apr-18    0           2019-01-17T06:16:59.000Z    sample  2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
ccaa/01APR2018-revised/content_01APR2018-00000.csv  1-Apr-18    1-Apr-18    115814528   2018-12-05T23:38:10.000Z    live    2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
ccaa/01APR2018-revised/content_01APR2018-00001.csv  1-Apr-18    1-Apr-18    116584541   2018-12-05T23:38:09.000Z    test    2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
ccaa/01JUN2018-revised/content_01JUN2018-00002.csv  1-Jun-18    1-Jun-18    117363985   2018-12-05T23:38:09.000Z    sample  2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
ccaa/01JUL2018-revised/content_10JUL2018-00002.csv  10-Jul-18   10-Jul-18   117363985   2018-12-05T23:38:09.000Z    sample  2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
ccaa/01AUG2018-revised/content_21AUG2018-00002.csv  21-Aug-18   21-Aug-18   117363985   2018-12-05T23:38:09.000Z    sample  2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
```

Scenario 2:

In this scenario, the string format in the filename is completely changed and format is YYYYMM.

```
filename                        size        date                        tname
ccaa/201802/                    0           2019-01-17T06:16:34.000Z    sample
ccaa/201802/Feb2018000000_0.csv 32602738    2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z    live
ccaa/201802/Feb2018000001_0.csv 32602738    2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z    test
ccaa/201802/Feb2018000002_0.csv 32602738    2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z    sample
ccaa/201802/Feb2018000003_0.csv 32602187    2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z    sample
```

Here, one of the tricky thing is based on the YYYYMM format, need to populate the start_dt and end_dt column with 30 days period of date. refer the content below

```
filename                            start_dt    end_dt      size        date                        tname
ccaa/201802/                                                0           2019-01-17T06:16:34.000Z    sample
ccaa/201803/March2018000000_0.csv   1-Mar-18    31-Mar-18   32602738    2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z    live
ccaa/201804/Apr2018000001_0.csv     1-Apr-18    30-Apr-18   32602738    2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z    test
ccaa/201805/May2018000002_0.csv     1-May-18    31-May-18   32602738    2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z    sample
ccaa/201808/Aug2018000003_0.csv     1-Aug-18    30-Aug-18   32602187    2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z    sample
```

Scenario 3:

Another scenario is to get the string (2018_Q1). and this need to populate as per quarterly based on the keyword like Q1,Q2,Q3 and Q4.

The output to be like below

```
filename                            start_dt    end_dt          size    date                        tname
ccll/2018_Q1/                                                   0       2019-01-17T06:16:34.000Z    sample
ccll/2018_Q1/March2018000000_0.csv  1-Jan-18    31-Mar-18   32602738    2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z    live
ccll/2018_Q2/Apr2018000001_0.csv    1-Apr-18    30-Jun-18   32602738    2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z    test
ccll/2018_Q3/May2018000002_0.csv    1-Jul-18    30-Sep-18   32602738    2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z    sample
```

Comment: `date` allows to convert an input string into output as date. `sed` or `cut` or `awk` with `while read` loop are just enough to parse csv separated files, but `join` and `comm` and `grep` and `expr substr` and bash variable expansions come very much in handy.

Comment: Cuk, I am intermediate on shell script. Could you please explain with an example and that would be great help for me.

Comment: The files don't look comma separated, probably are tabs separated. Take it one step a time. First [How to read file field by field](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) ie. `while IFS=$'\t' read -r  filename filesize data tname createddt; do echo "filseize=$filesize data=$data $(date .... )"; done < "file.csv"` date: [man date](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) ie. `LC_ALL=C date -d 2018-12-05T23:38:10.000Z +%m-%b-%g` LC_ALL may be needed for english language https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/070 also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002

Comment: For the `YYYYMM` seems like you can just use [dirname](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dirname.1.html) with [basename](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/basename.1.html) fom the filename, and you will get the string `201802`. Then some formatting, ie. extract year with `echo "$str" | cut -c4` and month, and do `date -d "$year-$month-01T00:00:00"`. Try to give `date` always full timestamp format, so it does not fail. then just `date ... +%Y-Q%q` to get `YYYY_Qq`.

Comment: Cuk, How to get the last day date of the each month extracted from the string as said above in the question 
for: I am able to populate start_dt for the string "201802" as "01-02-2018" but I am struggling to get the end_dt - which should be the last day date of the month (28-02-2018).

Comment: I am able to manage and write the code for scenario #1 and #2

`awk -F '[/]' '{print $2}' ub_cl.log | while  read -r f1
do
if [ ${#f1} -gt 7 ]; then
    (date -d "$f1" '+%Y-%m-%d %T' ) | ( awk -F, -v OFS=,  '{print $1, $1}')
else
    v_ab=`echo "${f1}01"`
 (((date -d "$v_ab" '+%Y-%m-%d %T') ;  (date -d "$(date -d "$v_ab" '+%Y-%m-%d %T') +1 month" '+%Y-%m-%d %T') | sed 's/^\|$//g'| paste -sd, - ) | sed -e 's/^\|$//g' |     paste -sd, - )
fi
done ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments in code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Scenario 1

echo 'filename    filesize    data_received_dt    tname   createdt
ccaa/01APR2018-revised/ 0   2019-01-17T06:16:59.000Z    sample  2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
ccaa/01APR2018/content_01APR2018-00000.csv  115814528   2018-12-05T23:38:10.000Z    live    2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
ccaa/01APR2018-revised/content_01APR2018-00001.csv  116584541   2018-12-05T23:38:09.000Z    test    2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
ccaa/01JUN2018-revised/content_01JUN2018-00002.csv  117363985   2018-12-05T23:38:09.000Z    sample  2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
ccaa/10JUL2018/content_10JUL2018-00002.csv  117363985   2018-12-05T23:38:09.000Z    sample  2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
ccaa/21AUG2018-revised/content_21AUG2018-00002.csv  117363985   2018-12-05T23:38:09.000Z    sample  2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
' |
# remove first line with headers
tail -n +2 |
# for each line
while 
    IFS=' ' read -r name size received_dt tname create_dt &&
    # stop on empty lines
    [ -n "$name" ]
do

    # get the second directory name from the name
    # this is a smarty way of getting the last second field from the right
    dir=$(<<<"$name" rev | cut -d'/' -f2 | rev)

    # if the 2nd dir doesn't end with -revised, add -revised 
    # (I think this could be just one sed command)
    if ! <<<"$dir" grep -q -- "-revised$"; then
        dir2=$(dirname "$(dirname "$name")")
        dir="${dir}-revised"
        name=$dir2/$dir/$(basename "$name")
    fi

    # extract date data from the dir
    day_from_dir=${dir:0:2}
    month_from_dir="${dir:2:1}$(<<<"${dir:3:2}" tr [:upper:] [:lower:])"
    year_from_dir="20${dir:7:2}"

    # get start and end dates
    start_dt=$(
        LC_ALL=C date \
        --date="${day_from_dir} ${month_from_dir} ${year_from_dir} 00:00:00" \
        +%-d-%b-%g
    )
    end_dt=$start_dt

    # printf ouput
    printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n" \
        "$name" \
        "$start_dt" \
        "$end_dt" \
        "$size" \
        "$received_dt" \
        "$tname" \
        "$create_dt"

done |
# format the output - left justify and set column names
column -t -s ' ' -o '  ' -N \
    "filename,start_dt,end_dt,filesize,data_received_dt,name,createdt"


# Scenario 2

echo 'filename                        size        date                        tname
ccaa/201802/                    0           2019-01-17T06:16:34.000Z    sample
ccaa/201802/Feb2018000000_0.csv 32602738    2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z    live
ccaa/201804/Feb2018000001_0.csv 32602738    2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z    test
ccaa/201805/Feb2018000002_0.csv 32602738    2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z    sample
ccaa/201806/Feb2018000003_0.csv 32602187    2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z    sample
' |
tail -n +2 |
while 
    IFS=' ' read -r name size date tname && [ -n "$name" ]
do
    # get the second directory name from the name
    # this is a smarty way of getting the last second field from the right
    dir=$(<<<"$name" rev | cut -d'/' -f2 | rev)

    # extract date from dir
    year=${dir:0:4}
    month=${dir:4:2}
    ts="${year}-${month}-01T00:00:00-00:00"

    # set date format
    start_dt=$(
        LC_ALL=C date \
        --date="$ts" \
        +%-d-%b-%g
    )
    # we want last month day - add 1 month and subtract 1 day
    end_dt=$(
        LC_ALL=C date \
        --date="$ts +1 month -1 day" \
        +%-d-%b-%g
    )

    # and output
    printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s\n" \
        "$name" \
        "$start_dt" \
        "$end_dt" \
        "$size" \
        "$date" \
        "$tname"

done |
column -t -s ' ' -o '  ' -N \
"filename,start_dt,end_dt,size,date,tname"

# Scenario 3 - same as 2 but different naming scheme or smth

echo 'filename                        size        date                        tname
ccaa/201802/                    0           2019-01-17T06:16:34.000Z    sample
ccaa/201802/Feb2018000000_0.csv 32602738    2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z    live
ccaa/201804/Feb2018000001_0.csv 32602738    2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z    test
ccaa/201805/Feb2018000002_0.csv 32602738    2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z    sample
ccaa/201808/Feb2018000003_0.csv 32602187    2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z    sample
' |
tail -n +2 |
while 
    IFS=' ' read -r name size date tname &&
    [ -n "$name" ]
do
    # get the second directory name from the name
    # this is a smarty way of getting the last second field from the right
    dir=$(<<<"$name" rev | cut -d'/' -f2 | rev)


    #extract date from dir
    year=${dir:0:4}
    month=${dir:4:2}
    ts="${year}-${month}-01T00:00:00-00:00"
    quarter=$(
        LC_ALL=C date \
        --date="$ts" \
        +%q
    )

    #rename the file with the year-Qq
    tmp="$(dirname "$(dirname "$name")")/${year}-Q${quarter}/"
    if ! <<<"$name" grep -q "/$"; then
        name="${tmp}$(basename "$name")"
    fi

    # set date format
    start_dt=$(
        LC_ALL=C date \
        --date="$ts" \
        +%-d-%b-%g
    )
    # we want last month day - add 1 month and subtract 1 day
    end_dt=$(
        LC_ALL=C date \
        --date="$ts  +1 month -1 day" \
        +%-d-%b-%g
    )

    # and output
    printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s\n" \
        "$name" \
        "$start_dt" \
        "$end_dt" \
        "$size" \
        "$date" \
        "$tname"

done |
# add create nice looking table with header names
column -t -s ' ' -o '  ' -N \
"filename,start_dt,end_dt,size,date,tname"
```

Output from [jdoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/test-bash-shell-script-online):

```
filename                                            start_dt   end_dt     filesize   data_received_dt          name    createdt
ccaa/01APR2018-revised/                             1-Apr-18   1-Apr-18   0          2019-01-17T06:16:59.000Z  sample  2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
ccaa/01APR2018-revised/content_01APR2018-00000.csv  1-Apr-18   1-Apr-18   115814528  2018-12-05T23:38:10.000Z  live    2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
ccaa/01APR2018-revised/content_01APR2018-00001.csv  1-Apr-18   1-Apr-18   116584541  2018-12-05T23:38:09.000Z  test    2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
ccaa/01JUN2018-revised/content_01JUN2018-00002.csv  1-Jun-18   1-Jun-18   117363985  2018-12-05T23:38:09.000Z  sample  2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
ccaa/10JUL2018-revised/content_10JUL2018-00002.csv  10-Jul-18  10-Jul-18  117363985  2018-12-05T23:38:09.000Z  sample  2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
ccaa/21AUG2018-revised/content_21AUG2018-00002.csv  21-Aug-18  21-Aug-18  117363985  2018-12-05T23:38:09.000Z  sample  2018-03-15T09:51:36.000Z
filename                         start_dt  end_dt     size      date                      tname
ccaa/201802/                     1-Feb-18  28-Feb-18  0         2019-01-17T06:16:34.000Z  sample
ccaa/201802/Feb2018000000_0.csv  1-Feb-18  28-Feb-18  32602738  2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z  live
ccaa/201804/Feb2018000001_0.csv  1-Apr-18  30-Apr-18  32602738  2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z  test
ccaa/201805/Feb2018000002_0.csv  1-May-18  31-May-18  32602738  2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z  sample
ccaa/201806/Feb2018000003_0.csv  1-Jun-18  30-Jun-18  32602187  2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z  sample
filename                          start_dt  end_dt     size      date                      tname
ccaa/201802/                      1-Feb-18  28-Feb-18  0         2019-01-17T06:16:34.000Z  sample
ccaa/2018-Q1/Feb2018000000_0.csv  1-Feb-18  28-Feb-18  32602738  2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z  live
ccaa/2018-Q2/Feb2018000001_0.csv  1-Apr-18  30-Apr-18  32602738  2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z  test
ccaa/2018-Q2/Feb2018000002_0.csv  1-May-18  31-May-18  32602738  2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z  sample
ccaa/2018-Q3/Feb2018000003_0.csv  1-Aug-18  31-Aug-18  32602187  2018-09-11T04:05:38.000Z  sample
```

- don't use backticks ` for command substitution, they don't allow nesting, are unreadable and deprecated. Use `$( ... )` instead.